# How to ondragover change color of droppable area in jQuery droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, droppable

Please see my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fletchadam/mr5Uj/15/

When you drag an item from the top I wish for the individual droppable area you hover over to change color.

I believe the trick is in this function:

```
function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
```

Comment: check this https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation

Answer (score 4):

Simply add your style in your allowDrop function :

```
function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(ev.target).css('background-color','#F00');
}
```

This will put a red background on the element. Now to remove it, use the `dragleave` event :

```
<div id="div1" class="droparea clearfix" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="removeStyle(event)">drag here</div>
```

With this Js function :

```
function removeStyle(ev) {
     $(ev.target).removeAttr('style');
}
```

The trick is to use the `target` of the event, which is your hovered div.